# Spring transaction management in integration tests

Tags: java, spring, testing, transactions

Currently I'm reading the Spring Framework documentation about testing. And I cannot interpret correctly the following section:

> By default, the framework creates and rolls back a transaction for each test.

Original link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testing-tx

As far as I understand, by default means the we don't need to annotate test method or class with @Transactional annotation to create a transaction for the method. But what I see in practice, if I skip annotating the method or class with the mentioned annotaion - the transaction won't be created.

Comment: That's just bad wording - what they mean is "by default when TestContext sees `@Transactional`"

Answer (score 0):

The @Transactional annotation is to indicate that a transaction is expected to happen in the method. This is expected for transnational use cases.

The benefit which the TestContext framework provides to us is that, when it sees an @Transactional annotation, then If you perform an insert query in a test case, then after the test case is over, framework will take care of automatically rolling back the insert query to bring back the DB to its old state. This ensures all the test cases have the same state of DB during its run. Else if this does not happen, every test case would alter the state of the DB and it might result in unwanted results.

if this had not been the case, we/user must take care of recreating the DB after every test case.

If you want to rollback after sending a web request, you could use the @DirtiesContext annotation to reset your context

Comment: You certainly don't want to re-create the context, this is too slow. There are much better ways of isolating tests like data randomization: http://qala.io/blog/randomized-testing.html

Comment: @sridhar yep, I understand that, the question was just about putting the Transactional annotation on the test method/class.